# How to define Text Color in Attributes files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tooltip

I am creating a Tooltip, I am using [this](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip) library to create one. Its described following `attr` to change Font color, This is the code to add in `attr.xml` files

```
declare-styleable name="TooltipLayout">
    <attr name="ttlm_padding" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="ttlm_strokeColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="ttlm_backgroundColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="ttlm_strokeWeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="ttlm_cornerRadius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="ttlm_arrowRatio" format="float" />
    <attr name="android:textAppearance" />
    <attr name="ttlm_overlayStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="ttlm_elevation" format="dimension" />

    <!-- font file path inside your assets folder -->
    <attr name="ttlm_font" format="string" />

    <!-- textview text gravity -->
    <attr name="android:gravity" />
</declare-styleable>
```

This may be quite easy, but i am unable to understand how to give color and specify values  in `attr` file.

Kindly guide me.

**EDIT**

Code

```
Tooltip.make(context,
                                            new Tooltip.Builder(101)
                                                    .anchor(editText, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                                                    .closePolicy(new Tooltip.ClosePolicy()
                                                            .insidePolicy(true, false)
                                                            .outsidePolicy(true, false), 3000)
                                                    .text("AA")
                                                    .maxWidth(800)
                                                    .withArrow(true)
                                                    .withOverlay(true)
                                                    .floatingAnimation(Tooltip.AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT).fitToScreen(true)
                                                    .withStyleId(R.attr.ttlm_backgroundColor,R.color.black_54)
                                                    .withStyleId(R.color.black)

                                                    .build()
                                    ).show();
```

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking, you don't specify the colors' values there in `attrs`. That's just where you define the attributes that you can assign values. The actual values are specified in the layout, or theme.

Comment: yes, thats what i am asking, so do i need to write following  in code? R.ttlm_padding = something?

Comment: In your layout xml where you define a view of the type TooltipLayout. The attributes you defined for it in this file will be available there and you can do someColorAttribute = *your color* e.g. ttlm_strokeColor=0xFFFFFFFF for white stroke color.

Comment: but i am not using any layout file to use create `tooltip`. Its all generating from code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using declare-stylable. As, which the name implies, is used for defining `what` you can style not `how`.

This enables you to set the styles in your layouts.

```
<com.mypackage.MyCustomView
android:layout_width=".."
...
app:ttlm_cornerRatius="4dp" />
```

You should then in your customView get your styled attributes and apply them to the view. For example

```
public ToolTipLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs); //override the constructors and make an init method that passes the `AttributeSet`
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable. TooltipLayout);
    int buttonType = a.getInt(R.styleable.TooltipLayout_ ttlm_cornerRadius, 0);
    a.recycle();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

ps. typed this out of my head, might have some typos.

Comment: Thanks, I need to add the `attr` in `withStyleId`. Kindly guide me how to add to add `attr` here, right now its giving me error message